# Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: python, json

If my json file is huge it contains to many dictionaries and lists inside the dictionary and it is enclosed with double quotes means how can i proceed that. what is the deserialize? How to use the  deserialize?

Comment: use ```json``` module

Comment: You can first read the file as string. Then you can remove the  ' " ' using string slicing. Then you can read the json file using json.load()

Comment: What do you mean, "enclosed with double quotes"?

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? What do you mean by "enclosed with double quotes" - does this happen when ``print``ing it, or with ``repr``? JSON en/decoders are part of the Python standard library, have you tried using them?

Comment: It sounds like you might have a JSON string that is itself encoded in *another* JSON string -- but without an example of the format so we can see where and how backslashes are used and otherwise what the details are, we can't be certain any answer we give is correct. Please be sure you provide a [mre] to allow answers and assumptions they're based on to be tested.

Comment: @satindersingh, rarely is just taking quotes off with slicing the right thing. After all, any kind of quoted representation that's designed for machine parsing will need to escape internal quotes to distinguish them from closing ones. Some formats escape things by doubling them, changing `"` to `""`; some formats escape things by adding sigil characters, like backslashes (which means that they then *also* need to escape instances of that sigil); without knowing how the internal data was modified by the code that also added the quotes, we can't know what answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Use **json** module.

If you are having json in one file then you can use:

```
with open("json_data.json", "r") as data:
  print(json.load(data))
```

OR

```
with open("json_data.json", "r") as data:
  print(json.loads(data.read()))
```

If you are having json in any var, you can use:

```
jsonData = '{}'
jsonVal = json.loads(jsonData)
```

Comment: This answer is already given in the knowledge base, many times over; if it is fully complete and applicable, then the question itself is a duplicate and should be closed instead of answered. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: (I suspect that their real format is more complicated, and thus that this answer is not fully complete and applicable -- maybe their JSON data is *itself* encoded as JSON, or as the `repr()` of the Python string with the JSON, which would explain the objection about double quotes; we have duplicates for that question too, but would need details from the OP to select a narrower/more specific instance).

Answer (score -1):

There is a package called **json** in python, which you can use to serialize and deserialize a dictionary.
If you want to serialize using the following:

```
with open("huge_json_file.json", "r") as data
    json_str = json.dumps(data)
```

If you want to de-serialize using the following:

```
with open("huge_json_file.json", "r") as data    
    json_dict = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: This answer is already given in the knowledge base, many times over; if it is fully complete and applicable, then the question itself is a duplicate and should be closed instead of answered. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer